# File changes in SmartGit in single window

Tags: smartgit

SmartGit shows file changes in two-windowed mode. How to set it in one-window mode like Git Extensions or SourceTree? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I've been using SmartGit for a while and discovered that two-windowed mode is its really killer-feature. After some adaptation it's much easier to read code changes (although the algorithm still needs in little improvement) compare to all other git clients. It was worth it, no doubt.

Comment: Are you referring to the **Change** view? And you want to see a `git diff`output instead?

Comment: Yes, the "Changes" view. I just want to see current version of file with changes highlighting green/red instead of old and new versions in separated windows.

Comment: Such a diff view is not available in SmartGit.

Comment: @mstrap Nonsense. All the git clients support this - Git Extensions, Source Tree, GitHub Desctop... Why SmartGit is so special? Or I misunderstood something and it is killer-feature that better than single-window diff?

Comment: Have a look at SmartGit 17.1 preview 10 for which compact changes view is supported now: https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/changelog-eap.txt

Comment: It is not the single-window mode anyway... Ok, is there some instruction about how to read changes view? For example, what does mean violet highlighting against red?

Comment: The used colors you can configure in the preferences. Why do you want to see an ugly diff output instead of a human readable file content compare?

Comment: Oh, I had already received all the answers at your forum, thank you and your colleague. I've updated my question, cause it is no actual for me anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartGit supports Unified diff since 21.1:
[image]